How to extract coefficients from a rational expression
I try to extract the following coefficients from a rational expression, but something that seems so simple mathematica cannot do it $$\frac{3 \left(9 \sqrt{39}-13 i\right)}{26 \left(4 i k+3 i+\sqrt{39}\right)}+\frac{3 \left(9 \sqrt{39}+13 i\right)}{26 \left(-4 i k-3 i+\sqrt{39}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\to \frac{a(1)}{b(1)+c(1) k}+\frac{a(2)}{b(2)+c(2) k}+\text{a0}$$ I have try
  expandedExpr = FullSimplify[expr];
expandedDesiredForm = FullSimplify[desiredForm];

sol = SolveAlways[expandedExpr == expandedDesiredForm, k] // Last
desiredForm /. sol

but do not work

Where is the code for the expression on interest?

Your problem has infinite number of solutions --- rescaling $a(i)$, $b(i)$, $c(i)$ by a common multiplier, swapping two sets of $a,b,c$-tuples.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems the problem is a misunderstanding of the Maths instead of a programming issue in Wolfram Language.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 3 (9 Sqrt[39] - 13 I)/(26 (4 I*k + 3 I + Sqrt[39])) +
   3 (9 Sqrt[39] + 13 I)/(26 (-4 I*k - 3 I + Sqrt[39])) - 1/2;

expr2 = List @@ expr;

n = -1;
repl = Flatten[(n++; If[FreeQ[#, k],
      {a[n] -> #},
      Flatten[{a[n] -> Numerator[#],
        Thread[{b[n], c[n]} ->
          CoefficientList[Denominator[#], k]]}]]) & /@
   expr2]

(* {a[0] -> -(1/2), a[1] -> 3 (13 I + 9 Sqrt[39]), 
 b[1] -> -78 I + 26 Sqrt[39], c[1] -> -104 I, 
 a[2] -> 3 (-13 I + 9 Sqrt[39]), b[2] -> 78 I + 26 Sqrt[39], 
 c[2] -> 104 I} *)

expr3 = Total[Flatten[
    {a[0], (a[#]/(b[#] + c[#] k) & /@
       Range[Length[expr2] - 1])}] /. repl]

(* -(1/2) + (3 (13 I + 9 Sqrt[39]))/(-78 I + 26 Sqrt[39] - 104 I k) + 
 (3 (-13 I + 9 Sqrt[39]))/(78 I + 26 Sqrt[39] + 104 I k) *)

expr == expr3 // Simplify

(* True *)


Consider for instance the following setup:
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
b[1] = 1;
b[2] = 2;
c[1] = 3;
c[2] = 5;
a[0] = 7;
y[x_] = Together[a[0] + a[1]/(b[1] + c[1] x) + a[2]/(b[2] + c[2] x)]

$$y(x)=\frac{105 x^2+88 x+18}{(3 x+1) (5 x+2)}.$$
Free term can be found as
z = Apart[y[x]]
A[0] = Select[z, FreeQ[#, x] &]
(* 7 *)

The rest can be reconstructed from poles and residues
FunctionPoles[z, x]
(* {{-(1/3), 1}, {-(2/5), 1}} *)

This answer also demonstrates that there is not a unique mathematical solution.

Thanks,@yarchick but given a rational function, find the coefficients according to the given model of continuous fraction

@capea You have not presented the function in MA form in your post. It is not given.  I had to invent one. Please, improve your post if you want a tailored answer.
